# Starting celery spaws 20 workers. How?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I'm deploying(daemonizing) celery. Following is my celeryd file.

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3 worker4"

CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="proj:app"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/path/to/proj/"

CELERYD_OPTS="-n %N@%h --config=proj.celeryconfig -l DEBUG --without-heartbeat"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

When I start celeryd, it spawns 20 processes. Why and how? My server has 4 CPUs.

Upon firing the below command

```
ps aux|grep 'celery worker'
```

Following is the output.

```
gfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker1.pid --hostname=worker1@worker1@worker1@worker1@%h
celery   26652  5.7  0.8 270340 66892 ?        S    18:41   0:02 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker2.pid --hostname=worker2@worker2@worker2@worker2@%h
celery   26662  1.0  0.7 860128 59364 ?        Sl   18:41   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker1.pid --hostname=worker1@worker1@worker1@worker1@%h
celery   26663  1.1  0.7 565456 59584 ?        S    18:41   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker1.pid --hostname=worker1@worker1@worker1@worker1@%h
celery   26664  1.6  0.7 860384 59624 ?        Sl   18:41   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker1.pid --hostname=worker1@worker1@worker1@worker1@%h
celery   26665  0.2  0.7 270272 59672 ?        S    18:41   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker1.pid --hostname=worker1@worker1@worker1@worker1@%h
celery   26668  5.3  0.8 270340 66656 ?        S    18:41   0:02 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker3.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker3.pid --hostname=worker3@worker3@worker3@worker3@%h
celery   26682  0.3  0.7 270272 58048 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker2.pid --hostname=worker2@worker2@worker2@worker2@%h
celery   26683  0.1  0.7 270272 58044 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker2.pid --hostname=worker2@worker2@worker2@worker2@%h
celery   26684  0.3  0.7 270272 58044 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker2.pid --hostname=worker2@worker2@worker2@worker2@%h
celery   26685  0.2  0.7 270272 58108 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker2.pid --hostname=worker2@worker2@worker2@worker2@%h
celery   26687  5.5  0.8 270340 66824 ?        S    18:42   0:02 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker4.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker4.pid --hostname=worker4@worker4@worker4@worker4@%h
celery   26696  0.1  0.7 270272 58036 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker3.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker3.pid --hostname=worker3@worker3@worker3@worker3@%h
celery   26697  1.3  0.7 861124 60648 ?        Sl   18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker3.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker3.pid --hostname=worker3@worker3@worker3@worker3@%h
celery   26698  0.1  0.7 270272 58032 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker3.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker3.pid --hostname=worker3@worker3@worker3@worker3@%h
celery   26699  0.1  0.7 270272 58100 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker3.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker3.pid --hostname=worker3@worker3@worker3@worker3@%h
celery   26701  0.0  0.7 270272 57720 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker4.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker4.pid --hostname=worker4@worker4@worker4@worker4@%h
celery   26702  0.0  0.6 270080 53260 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker4.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker4.pid --hostname=worker4@worker4@worker4@worker4@%h
celery   26703  0.0  0.7 270272 57268 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker4.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker4.pid --hostname=worker4@worker4@worker4@worker4@%h
celery   26704  0.0  0.7 270272 57336 ?        S    18:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python -m celery worker --without-heartbeat -l DEBUG --config=c26_message.celeryconfig --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker4.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/worker4.pid --hostname=worker4@worker4@worker4@worker4@%h
root     26740  0.0  0.0  14196   984 pts/5    S+   18:42   0:00 grep --color=auto celery worker
```

Celery flower also shows 20 workers, out of which 16 are offline and 4 are online. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is 4 Nodes is created and default concurrrency settings based on number of CPU. So, you can see each nodes created 5 process.

Set each concurrency node by referring to example as below to set one node per CPU:

`CELERYD_OPTS="-c 4 -c:worker4 1 -c:worker3 1 -c:worker2 1 -c:worker1 1"`

May refer example configuration of celery documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#example-configuration